# Animation overriding onNavigateUp's default one

Tags: android, overriding, android-animation, transition

I am launching an About Activity with `overridePendingTransition()` right after it, so I can get an animation of the incoming Activity.

I want the Activity to perform an animation as well upon "leaving", so I have overriden `onBackPressed()` and it works ok.

The problem comes, as the About activity has the "Up navigation" enabled, on how to perform the animation when the "Up" navigation is tapped --instead of just Back button-- to return to previous activity.

I have tried

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigateUp() {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadeinltr, R.anim.fadeoutltr);
    return super.onNavigateUp();
}
```

but it does not work, because by the time the `overridePendingTransition()` method is called, there is no transition to override yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but you can try setting a boolean flag in `onNavigateUp` then reading it in `finish()` and override the animation if the flag is set.

Comment: @dmon does not seem to be working...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved in this way:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigateUp(){
    boolean x = super.onNavigateUp();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    return x;
}
```